# How to configure your database to automatically open in a separate window?

Tags: database, lotus-notes, lotus

How can I set my lotus notes databases to automatically open in a separate window, like the the help files (databases)? And even better, is there a way to open the database without opening the lotus notes client? I'm using 8.5.3 LN client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a Notes database in a separate window, like the Help database, do this:

1. Select your database's icon on the workspace.
2. Choose File - Database - Properties and click the design tab
3. Turn on "List in Database Catalog" and enter "NotesHelp" under Categories.
4. Open the database. If it does not immediately appear in the special window, close it, remove its icon from the workspace, exit and restart Notes, and open it again.

Source: http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/helpex6.nsf/769e1b028f863f84852566c100358467/9ed8b1f2376afcde8525670c006fc870?OpenDocument&AutoFramed

Answer (score 1):

You can't really open a Notes database without starting the Notes client.  But try a command line like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Lotus\Notes\nlnotes.exe /kiosk "your server/your org!!path/database.nsf"
```

It might be what you want.  Or not.  It's hard to tell from your question.